# Oracle 12c pluggable database won't start

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, startup, sysdba, pluggable-database

After running some scripts to install/uninstall Oracle Application Express (APEX), now my pluggable database won't start. I get the (uninformative) error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
```

I checked the log file, but there is no more information than this.

This is a development database running in a Linux virtual machine (Oracle VirtualBox) on a Windows 7 host. I am running Oracle 12.1 with a container database and one pluggable database.  It has been working for years.
With the database not started, at the linux command line I connect with

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

and issue the startup command.  The container database starts up normally.  Then I run

```
alter session set container=[my pluggable database]
```

which succeeds, but when I issue the startup command, I get the errors listed above.
Suggestions?

Comment: So, the issue is when you try 'alter pluggable database ... open;'?

Comment: Looks like a corruption in metadata in APEX install/uninstall is blocking the opening of PDB. Can you please try opening the PDB in `read only` mode? `alter pluggable database <pdb_name> open read only;`

Comment: Tried that, same error.

Comment: Happy New Year! Still stuck, hoping someone might have more ideas.

Comment: I have the same problem - after installing Apex, the database can't be opened.